# WCF REST - parameterless GET not working

Tags: wcf, rest

I'm trying to get the most basic operation working for my WCF restful service going.

I have a service on my local machine. Let's call it TeskService:

```
http://localhost:52309/Services/TaskService.svc
```

On the back end, I have a WebGet:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITaskService
{  
    [WebGet]
    void CreateTask();

}
```

If I type the following into my browser, nothing gets triggered (I get a 404):

```
http://localhost:52309/Services/TaskService.svc/CreateTask
```

If I change my definition to accept a parameter:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="CreateTask/*")]
void CreateTask();
```

And then pass in any value:

```
http://localhost:52309/Services/TaskService.svc/CreateTask/randomText
```

Then the method triggers.

I don't want to pass in anything. I just want the method to fire. What am I doing incorrectly?

According to this link:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

they have

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ICustomer
{
  //"View It"

  [WebGet]
  Customer GetCustomer():


}
```

and calling it using /GetCustomer should be fine.

Ideas? Thoughts? Inspiration?

This is proving to be more difficult for me than it should be.

EDIT:

Could it be affected by my MVC routing in the same project?

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}",
defaults: new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
}
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use `[WebGet]`

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITaskService
    {  
       [WebGet]
       void CreateTask();
    }
```

then you can call using `http://localhost:52309/Services/TaskService.svc/CreateTask`.

If you use `[WebGet(UriTemplate="")]`

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITaskService
    {  
      [WebGet(UriTemplate="")]
      void CreateTask();
    }
```

then you can call using `http://localhost:52309/Services/TaskService.svc`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I didn't realise is that WCF Rest has been replaced by WebAPI. I have been really stupid in this respect in that I've been using WebAPI for yonks already... but using self host inside WPF applications for another purpose. I didn't even consider hosting it inside an MVC application until further reading up.